# Splitting string into array then using one of the values to be displayed in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the code below which is in JSX format. `r.invoice_details` gives me an output that looks like this

`{"rate":1522,"quantity":1,"discount":null,"itemName":"Gold Members club (offline)","amount":1522,"noEdit":true}`

It's in a form of string. All I want is itemName inside the string to be displayed. What's the best way to write as an inline function?

```
{
  id: "itemName",
  label: "Item",
  customCell: (r, i) => {
    return <td key={`${i}-itemName`}>
      {r.invoice_details}
      </td>;
  }
},
```

Comment: if it's a string, use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) and you should be good no ?

Answer (score 1):

[You can use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) `JSON.parse()`

```js
const json = '{"rate":1522,"quantity":1,"discount":null,"itemName":"Gold Members club (offline)","amount":1522,"noEdit":true}';
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(obj.itemName);
```

So your end code will look something like this,

```
{
  id: "itemName",
  label: "Item",
  customCell: (r, i) => {
    return <td key={`${i}-itemName`}>
      {JSON.parse(r.invoice_details).itemName}
      </td>;
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I write it in the format above?

Comment: Thanks, the only issue is. I am getting this error

Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: Please provide more information on this error, if it is a cross-origin error might have to check the backend as well, again without information it is not possible to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) function:

`{JSON.parse(r.invoice_details).itemName}`

So your final code will look like this:

```
{
  id: "itemName",
  label: "Item",
  customCell: (r, i) => {
    return <td key={`${i}-itemName`}>
      {JSON.parse(r.invoice_details).itemName}
      </td>;
  }
},
```

Comment: done. mdn link added

Comment: @Paul this should be exactly what you need

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting this error when I write it this way.  
Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.

Comment: without more info, can't help you out.. sounds like an unrelated problem to the question you posted

Answer (score 0):

[Try Object.values after extractiong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) JSON.parse()

```js
  let json = JSON.parse(r.invoice_details)
   let inv =   Object.keys(json)
   let inv2 = Object.values(json)
   let Id = inv2[inv1.indexOf("itemName")]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).